# How to set container width conditionally in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a component having a container with no width initially. What I want is when I specify the full-width property to true, it takes double.infinity as the width otherwise it takes no width at all. This is my component:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfoColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  const InfoColumn({
    Key? key,
    required this.heading,
    required this.text,
    this.fullWidth = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String heading;
  final String text;
  final bool fullWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          heading,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Container(
          // TODO: SET WIDTH HERE
          // width: fullWidth ? double.infinity : ,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 30,
            vertical: 12,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried fullWidth ? double.infinity : 0.0

Comment: Very very basic flutter knowledge here, but `width: fullWidth ? double.infinity : null,` would be my first try.

Comment: @RenikShiroya Yeah! but 0.0 sets the width to 0. That is not what I want.

Comment: Can you include more about details, your expectation and what went wrong while implementing your x approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container `width` is nullable, and containers will only take up as much space as their children require.

A simple ternary statement will achieve what you're after:

```dart
Container(
  width: fullWidth ? double.infinity : null,
  // ...
),
```